# How to move and rename each file in folder to top folder? [linux shell] [bash]

Tags: bash, file, directory, rename, move

I'm trying to create a simple script in linux shell that *in a folderX* goes through each of its folders, renames the files that finds there, and moves them to the root (folderX) folder....
I'm guessing that the logic is somewhat like this:

```
-0> //in folderX
-0>for each folder == $folderY //just the last part, what comes after ~/folderX/[this]
    -1> cd ./$folderY
    -1> for each fileInY == $fileInY //just the last part, what comes after ~/folderX/folderY/[this.something]
        -2> rename fileInY = "$folderY - $fileInY"
    -1> move * to folderX
    -1> cd..
```

(but suggestions and different methods of approach are appreciated)

Thanks in advance!
-Gabix

Comment: You should be able to do this with a single find command that utilises -exec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
folder="folderX"
find "$folder" -type f -exec cp '{}' '{}'.bak \; -exec mv '{}'.bak "$folder" \;
```

Set the root folder/directory in a variable folder and then use this to run find and then exec. Find files in the directory structure and first copy the name of the file to the name of the file followed by ".bak" and then move the file from the directory to the root folder/directory

Comment: thanks!! Can you describe a little of how this process works?, i guess the -type f says to go through each folder as a function in the find cmd... but the '{}' and beyond I don't get... Does '{}' describes * (each file and folder) in the **return** from the **find** cmd?, then stores all in a temp.bak file (kind of like a zip), and then _decompress_ all renaming it in the process?

Comment: There is no compression. The files found are simply copied/renamed to another file of the same name followed by .bak in one exec command i.e. test to test.bak. In the second exec command, this .bak file is then moved back into the root directory.

Comment: Great! I wasn't implying compression, just my way of understanding and explaining the process,  ...and the script part? I'd like to have this in a **myMoveToTopCmd.sh**... does sh get input variables? can I call this script from somewhere, and call >sh **myMoveToTopCmd.sh** -"/my/root/folder/where/to/start/moving/stuff"

Comment: You you can add the command to a script and then use $1 instead of $folder. $1 signifies the first parameter passed to a script.

Comment: I get kinda lost with the \ and / ... doesn't the \ means it'll send everything to my root dir? or because it's a \, and not a /, everything will be sent to the $folder ($1) instead of my -total- root dir.

Comment: \; signifies the end of the command passed to -exec

Comment: ahh!! GREAT!! Thanks again for the bother!

Comment: No worries. If your happy with the solution, please take the time to accept it